# Solve the PDE $u_x+2xy^2 u_y=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the PDE $u_x+2xy^2 u_y=0$

Claim: the characteristic curves satisfy the ODE $dy/dx=2xy^2/1=2xy^2$.

Check: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2xy^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \rightarrow$ I get $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=-2xy^2$ I am not sure what's going wrong with this.

Comment: Implicit function theorem has a minus sign, i.e. $ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = - \frac{F_x}{F_y}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi i am not sure how to get rid of the minus sign. that's the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to get rid of, the algebra must have been done incorrectly.

Comment: CAS says:$u \left( x,y \right) ={\it C1} \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{-1} \right) $ where $C1 $ is arbitrary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_x+2xy^2u_y=0$$
Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2xy^2}=\frac{du}{0}$$
First characteristic equation from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2xy^2} \quad \implies\quad 2xdx-\frac{dy}{y^2}=0$
$$x^2+\frac{1}{y}=c_2$$ 
General solution on implicit form, from $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$u=F\left(x^2+\frac{1}{y}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).